# Firebase App - how to?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to develop two android apps. One app that store data into Firebase Firestore Database and second app shows that data. How I retrieve data from a different Firebase app.

Comment: it means how to read firebase to store data.

Comment: Please try at least some code after search and if you get errors ask here, no one will do all for you.

Comment: @SubinBabu That's why I have shared the tutorial and give an idea to achieve that. :)

Comment: @ArbazAlam Please provide code instead of links, links may get expired. But this case no try and no error log from savdhariya Sanjay

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve your scenario, create a project from Firebase console and then in that project add your both APPs. After that please follow the below link that will help you how to store and retrieve data in firebase database.

https://theengineerscafe.com/save-and-retrieve-data-firebase-android/

Please make a note that both apps should be added to the same project in firebase, otherwise your apps will not communicate with same database instance.

Comment: Please provide code instead of links, links may get expired.

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake.I have to provide at least official android page links, as those are managed by Google. Going forward I will keep in mind.